# Find the Least Common Multiple of Numbers using Prime Factorization (How to emulate Prime Table)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

My approach to this problem is most likely flawed, but I'm so close to finishing the solution. Given the numbers 2 and 10, I must find the least common multiple of the two numbers, plus the numbers within their range.
(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

I've created a function that is used to return the prime factors of every number, and push them into an array. This is where I'm lost. I don't know how to reduce/filter out the excessive prime numbers.

I should end up multiplying 2*2*2*3*3*5*7, but filtering unique numbers would result me with 2*3*5*7, or 2*3*2*5*2*3*7*2*3*2*5 if I filtered the numbers before the array was flattened.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
    // factorize a number function
    function factorization(num) {
        let primesArr = [];
        // i is what we will divide the number with
        for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
            // if number is divisible by i (with no remainder)
            if (num % i === 0) {
                // begin while loop that lasts as long as num is divisible by i
                while (num % i === 0) {
                    // change the value of num to be it divided by i
                    num = num / i;
                    // push the prime number used to divide num
                    primesArr.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        // if num is not the number 1 after the for loop
        // push num to the array because it is also a prime number
        if (num != 1) {
            primesArr.push(num);
        } 
        return primesArr;
    }
    // sort from lowest to highest
    arr.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    let range = [];
    let primeFacts = [];
    // push range of numbers to fullArr
    for (let i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }
    console.log(range); // [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    // loop for iterating through range numbers
    for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        // push the prime factors of each range number
        primeFacts.push(factorization(range[i]));
    }
    console.log(primeFacts); 
    // flatten the array, then return the product of numbers
    return primeFacts
                .reduce((newArray, arr) => newArray = [...newArray,...arr] ,[])
                .reduce((product, num) => product *= num); 
};

console.log(smallestCommons([2,10]));
```

OUTPUT

```
[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ [ 2 ],[ 3 ],[ 2, 2 ],[ 5 ],[ 2, 3 ],[ 7 ],[ 2, 2, 2 ],[ 3, 3 ],[ 2, 5 ] ]
3628800
```

How do I emulate this and add it in my code? ->
[Example of Table I want to emulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnzPi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Take this as a table of prime factors and their degrees:

```
    2  3  5  7
 2  1
 3     1
 4  2
 5        1
 6  2  2
 7           1
 8  3
 9     2
10  1     1
```

For the LCM, take the *largest* degree in each column:

```
    3  2  1  1
```

Multiply those powers together; that's your answer:

```
2^3 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^1
```

**EXTENSION**

To get the GCD, take the *smallest* degree in each column (including 0).

Comment: Right, I'm trying to figure out how to implement this into code.

Comment: Starting with the code you posted, your next problems are to set up, populate, and traverse the 2-D array.  Post again when you hit a SO-level blocking point.

Comment: I decided to change the returned value of the factorization function. It now returns an object. I then loop through the object to keep only the largest unique keys where the value is the greatest. Then, I loop through it again to create an array with the proper amount of prime numbers. Finally, I reduce the array into a product.

Comment: Excellent vectorization ... does it work?  If not, I recommend a separate question to resolve the final bits.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use prime factorization, or do you just need the lowest common multiples? Because there is another, much more efficient algorithm for it, called the Euclidean algorithm. You can read up on it here:

http://www.programming-algorithms.net/article/42865/Least-common-multiple
http://www.programming-algorithms.net/article/43434/Greatest-common-divisor

(note: calculating the LCM via the Euclidean algorithm requires the GCD, but there's a Euclidean algorithm for that too)

Now, the above mentioned algorithm works for two numbers, but I think (haven't mathematically verified it tho, so you need to check this yourself) you can just use left reduction.

The end result would look something like this:

```
var getLCM = (a, b) => {
    // Implement Euclidean LCM algorithm here...
};

var getTotalLCM = (numbers) => {
    return numbers.reduce((totalLCM, next) => getLCM(totalLCM, next), 1);
}

var result = getTotalLCM([ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]);
```

What `getTotalLCM` will do here, is it will calculate the LCM of 1 and 2 (1 because that's the initial accumulator value we passed to `reduce()`), which is of course 2. Then it calculates the LCM of 2 and 3, which is 6; then 6 and 4, which is 12, then 12 and 5, which is 60, then 6 and 60, which is still 60, and so on. I think this is what you're looking for?

More on how `reduce()` works here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found. The factorization function now returns an object instead with prime key exponent value pairs. Through for in loops, and the reduce method, the LCM is outputted.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
    // factorize a number function
    function factorization(num) {
        let primesObj = {};
        // i is what we will divide the number with
        for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
            // if number is divisible by i (with no remainder)
            if (num % i === 0) {
                let exponent = 0;
                // begin while loop that lasts as long as num is divisible by i
                while (num % i === 0) {
                    // change the value of num to be it divided by i
                    num = num / i;
                    exponent++;
                    // create key value pair where exponent is the value
                    primesObj[i] = exponent;
                }
            }
        }
        // if num is not the number 1 after the for loop
        // push num to the array because it is also a prime number
        if (num != 1) {
            primesObj[num] = 1;
        } 
        return primesObj;
    }
    // sort from lowest to highest
    arr.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    let range = [];
    let primeFacts = [];
    // push range of numbers to fullArr
    for (let i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }
    console.log(range); // [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    // loop for iterating through range numbers
    for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        // push the prime factors of each range number
        primeFacts.push(factorization(range[i]));
    }
    console.log(primeFacts); 
    // create a filtered object with only the largest key value pairs
    let primeExponents = primeFacts.reduce((newObj,currObj)=> {
        for (let prime in currObj) {
            // create new key value pair when key value pair does not exist
            if (newObj[prime] === undefined) {
                newObj[prime] = currObj[prime];
            }
            // overwrite key value pair when current Object value is larger
            else if (newObj[prime] < currObj[prime]) {
                newObj[prime] = currObj[prime];
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    },{});
    let finalArr = [];
    // push appropriate amount of primes to arr according to exponent
    for (let prime in primeExponents) {
        for (let i = 1; i <= primeExponents[prime]; i++) {
            finalArr.push(parseInt([prime]));
        }
    }
    return finalArr.reduce((product, num) => product *= num);
};

console.log(smallestCommons([2,10]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To go from the prime factorizations to the LCM, you need to count how many of each prime are needed at maximum. So for each factorization I would create a `map` of primes to counts. And I'd keep track of the highest number of each factor needed:

```
function lcm(primeFacts){
    var maxPrimes = {}; // stores the highest number of each prime factor required 
    for(var i = 0; i < primeFacts.length; i++){
        var map = {};
        var factors = primeFacts[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < factors.length; j++){
            // check to see whether the factor already exists in the map
            if(map[factors[j]]) map[factors[j]]++;
            else map[factors[j]] = 1;

            // check to make sure the max count exists
            if(!maxPrimes[factors[j]]) maxPrimes[factors[j]] = 1;
            if(maxPrimes[factors[j]] < map[factors[j]])
                maxPrimes[factors[j]] = map[factors[j]];
        }
    }
```

Then once we have all the counts for each factor, we just multiply them out:

```
    var multiple = 1;
    for(var prime in maxPrimes){
        multiple *= prime ^ maxPrimes[prime];
    }
}
```